# Plotting a line graph in R with a reversed x axis

Tags: r, plot, axes, x-axis

I am trying to plot a spectra in R with a revered x axis using matplot:

```r
matplot(x = colnames(aaaLowCarbonAbsorbanceSpec),
  y = t(aaaLowCarbonAbsorbanceSpec),
  main = "Low Carbon Absorbance", type = 'l',
  xlab = "Wavenumber / cm-1", ylab = "Absorbance",
  col = rgb(red = 1, green = 0.5, blue = 0.5, alpha = 1))
```

Plots the curve: [image: 1]

I used the `rev()` function in:

```r
matplot(x = rev(colnames(aaaLowCarbonAbsorbanceSpec)),
  y = t(aaaLowCarbonAbsorbanceSpec),
  main = "Low Carbon Absorbance Rev", type = 'l',
  xlab = "Wavenumber / cm-1", ylab = "Absorbance",
  col = rgb(red = 1, green = 0.5, blue = 0.5, alpha = 1))
```

and plotted: [image: 2]

But the x axis remains the same - how do I get it in descending order?

Thanks

Here is an image of my data frame: [image: 3]

Comment: Welcome to SO, owentwhite! (1) Are you really plotting the column names themselves? (2) If you reverse the x-axis, don't you also have to reverse the `y` values? (3) Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. The values are in the column names yes. Additionally, I get the same outcome when I rev() the y values aswell. I have attached an image of part of my dataframe.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 2):

### matplot

Change the `xlim=` for your plot.

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- setNames(as.data.frame(as.list(runif(10))), seq(4000, 3955, by=-5))
rownames(dat) <- "SOG130123"
dat
#               4000      3995      3990      3985      3980      3975      3970      3965      3960      3955
# SOG130123 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455 0.5190959 0.7365883 0.1346666 0.6569923 0.7050648

matplot(as.numeric(colnames(dat)), t(dat), type = "l")
```

[image: matplot with normal x-axis]

```r
matplot(as.numeric(colnames(dat)), t(dat), type = "l", xlim = c(4000, 3955))
```

[image: matplot with reversed x-axis]

### ggplot2

More data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(runif(30), ncol=10)), seq(4000, 3955, by=-5))
rownames(dat) <- c("SOG130123", "SOG130124", "SOG130125")
dat
#                4000      3995      3990      3985      3980      3975      3970      3965       3960      3955
# SOG130123 0.9148060 0.8304476 0.7365883 0.7050648 0.9346722 0.9400145 0.4749971 0.1387102 0.08243756 0.9057381
# SOG130124 0.9370754 0.6417455 0.1346666 0.4577418 0.2554288 0.9782264 0.5603327 0.9888917 0.51421178 0.4469696
# SOG130125 0.2861395 0.5190959 0.6569923 0.7191123 0.4622928 0.1174874 0.9040314 0.9466682 0.39020347 0.8360043
```

Reshape and plot:

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tibble) # rownames_to_column
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
library(ggplot2)
dat %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowname, names_to = "x", values_to = "y") %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = rowname, color = rowname)) +
  scale_x_reverse()
```

[image: ggplot2 equivalent of a matplot]

`dplyr` is not required to do this, nor is `tibble`, but they make it fairly simple to get things started. For reshaping data to support this, `ggplot2` really wants "long" data, and the two best tools to support that are `tidyr::pivot_longer` and `reshape2::melt` (and `data.table::melt`, nearly the same except for using `data.table` instead of a `data.frame` for data).